# Database for storing large documents

Tags: database, document

Can anyone suggest a database solution for storing large documents which will have multiple branched revisions? Partial edits of content should be possible without having to update the entire document.

I was looking at XML databases and wondering about the suitability of them, or maybe even using a DVCS (like Mercurial).

It should preferably have Python bindings.

Comment: define 'document'. Are you talking about large blocks of text, or actual file system document formats such as MS Word?

Comment: Large blocks of text -- they're all going to be normalized to some XML format.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.alfresco.com/?

Comment: @Jared I'm looking for something I can integrate into my own software, rather than something like an enterprise solution.

Comment: Oh ok. Mercurial is probably a good choice, maybe Git. Fossil looks good too.

Comment: Git has a Python binding library: http://gitorious.org/git-python

Answer (score 1):

Try [Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) -- it has a good delta encoding algorithm, and keeps all versions. It's backed by a single SQLite database, and has both a web based and a command line UI.

Comment: Does Fossil support partial edits (as in being able to extract a portion of the file and commit it back)?

Comment: You must commit the entire new document, but the delta encoding algorithm avoids duplication of content in the repository.

Comment: I don't really want to have to checkout the entire document, because they can be arbitrarily long.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your storage behavior and use case. If you plan to store a massive number of "document revisions" and keep historical versions, and can comply with a write-once-read-many pattern, you should look into something like Hadoop HDFS. This requires a lot of (cheap) infrastructure to run your cluster, but you will be able to keep adding revisions/data over time and will be able to quickly look it up using a MapReduce algorithm.

Comment: Sadly it's more write-many-read-many, and the writes aren't necessarily big.